# JAVA. Загрузка Item в ComboBox из Файла txt

Tags: java, combobox

Как можно добавлять Items в ComboBox из файла TXT, по нажатию кнопки? Вроде как-то можно через:

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path,Charset cs)
throws IOException
```

Мне, как новичку в Java, не понятно как это использовать, а ответа Гугл так и не дал.

```
ComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("000.txt"));
```

ругается на Items и ReadAllLines, импорт System.IO сделал, хотя просто через ComboBox.addItem("один"); добавляет нормально.

Comment: А Гугл так и написал: "ответы сегодня не даю"? Пожалуйста, укажите ключевые слова, по которым вы искали.

Comment: java add items to combobox from file